# Creating an object from every instance of class and content within that element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, dom

I am building out a function that will run through every instance of class, pull an id, and then pull the number of days associated and price that will be values of the id key. So for instance:

```
{
    {
        id: 1,
        info: {
            days: "5 days",
            price: "£300"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        info: {
            days: "9 days",
            price: "£500"
        }
    }
}
```

The function is as follows but only seems to do it for the last instance and doesn't return days or prices:

```
function sortTrips () {
    let tripObj = {};
    $('.tab#top10 .col-md-4').each(function(index, obj) {   
        tripObj.id = $(this).attr('id');
        tripObj.id.info.days = $(this).find('.days').html();
        tripObj.id.info.price = $(this).find('.price').html();
    });
    console.log(tripObj);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the data structure you're trying to build is invalid - you cannot have an anonymous nested object. An array of objects seems the closest valid solution to what you're trying to do.

Secondly, the `days` and `price` are missed out because you're trying to set them on an `info` object which doesn't yet exist.

You can solve both issues and tidy the code by using `map()`, like this:

```js
function sortTrips() {
  var tripObj = $('.tab#top10 .col-md-4').map(function() {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      info: {
        days: $(this).find('.days').html(),
        price: $(this).find('.price').html()
      }
    }
  }).get();
  
  console.log(tripObj);
}

sortTrips();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab" id="top10">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="foo">
      <div class="days">5 days</div>
      <div class="price">£300</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="bar">
      <div class="days">9 days</div>
      <div class="price">£500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="fizz">
      <div class="days">6 days</div>
      <div class="price">£600</div>
  </div>
</div>
```